# Clear approach for assigning semantic tags to each sentence (or short documents) in python

Tags: python-2.7, nlp, nltk, gensim, semantic-analysis

I am looking for a good approach using python libraries to tackle the following problem:

I have a dataset with a column that has product description. The values in this column can be very messy and would have a lot of other words that are not related to the product. I want to know which rows are about the same product, so I would need to tag each description sentence with its main topics. For example, if I have the following: 
"500 units shoe green sport tennis import oversea plastic", I would like the tags to be something like: "shoe", "sport". So I am looking to build an approach for semantic tagging of sentences, not part of speech tagging. Assume I don't have labeled (tagged) data for training.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lack of labeled data means you cannot apply any semantic classification method using word vectors, which would be the optimal solution to your problem. An alternative however could be to construct the document frequencies of your token n-grams and assume importance based on some smoothed variant of idf (i.e. words that tend to appear often in descriptions probably carry some semantic weight). You can then inspect your sorted-by-idf list of words and handpick(/erase) words that you deem important(/unimportant). The results won't be perfect, but it's a clean and simple solution given your lack of training data.

Comment: Thank you for the info! I am also exploring usefulness of Doc2Vec.